# /afs/ThisCell path resolution fails

Tags: linux, rhel, afs

When using AFS, you can specify paths as `/afs/ThisCell/...` instead of using the actual cell name and it will interpolate it for you. That's not working on my local machine, but all other AFS functionality seems to be working fine. I can still access files and directories if I specify the cell name instead of using `ThisCell`. If I log into one of our remote machines and attempt the same, then `ThisCell` works correctly.

I'm using OpenAFS 1.6.23 on RHEL 7.7. The remote machines are using the same version of OpenAFS and RHEL 7.5. I've verified that `/usr/vice/etc/ThisCell` exists on my machine and has the correct contents. `fs wscell` also returns the correct value. I restarted my machine, but that didn't help either.

Where should I start with this? What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per jsbillings' answer I don't think this is actually supported out of the box by AFS, but I was able to replicate this behavior with `sudo fs newalias -alias ThisCell -name $(</usr/vice/etc/ThisCell)`.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never heard of using /afs/ThisCell, and I can’t find any documentation for it.

You can use [fs newalias](https://docs.openafs.org/Reference/1/fs_newalias.html) to create cell aliases, if that’s a path you want, though.

Perhaps you are thinking of /etc/afs/ThisCell, which some installations of AFS use as the configuration path for the ThisCell file?  Or perhaps the people who manage the AFS clients with `/afs/ThisCell` have helpfully created this alias for end users?

Comment: I think that's probably what they did, our admins must have created this alias.

Comment: ...or maybe not? Running `fs listaliases` on a remote machine doesn't show any aliases for `ThisCell`. Who knows, maybe it's there but hidden or they did it using some other mechanism.